# Open an app from a JobService without "Display Over Other Apps" permission

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I am new to android development. I've been trying to open an app from a **JobService** that is scheduled from the `onReceive()` method of an implicit **broadcast-receiver**, declared in my manifest.

From some posts, I found that one can use the `packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()` method and then use it to launch said package by starting a new activty with `context.startActivity()`, so I declared the function below:

```
fun openApp(packageName: String, context: Context){
            val startIntent: Intent? =
                context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
            startIntent?.addFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            );
            context.startActivity(startIntent)
}
```

When used on the **MainActivity** file, this function works as expected, but when I try using it on my **JobService**, I noticed that it only works if my app has the **Display Over Other Apps** permission.

Is this to be expected? Is there any way to contourn this requirement? Is this because of the way I am passing the `context` in my `openApp()` function?

Thx in advance!

Comment: "Is this to be expected?" -- yes, as displaying activities from the background has been banned in recent versions of Android. Please raise a notification instead.

Comment: So I shouldn't be able to automatically open an app from the background? This is a required feature in my case... :/

Comment: "So I shouldn't be able to automatically open an app from the background?" -- correct. "This is a required feature in my case" -- interrupting the user by taking over the foreground has been considered to be a bad idea from the beginning. You do not know what the user is doing at the time, and the interruption could be a serious problem. For example, you might cause an accident if the user was relying on navigation at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CommonsWare's comments, I've found the documentation I needed:

**[Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)**.

In my use case, I needed to cancel a call to a specific number and open my app instead, so I adapted my code to take advantage of the **[CallRedirectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallRedirectionService)** class, which is treated as an exception and therefore can start activities from the background.